# Azure Pipeline deploy job with dynamic environment

Tags: azure-devops, azure-pipelines, azure-pipelines-yaml

We have two environments defined, "stage" and "prod". Prod requires approval for deploying, where as stage does not.

What I'm trying to achieve is that if the pipeline runs against the master branch, it should use the prod environment, and all other branches should use the stage environment.

Problem is that I can't seem to be able to change the environment in runtime. I've also tried using templates, which sort of works, except that I can't pass runtime information as parameters to the template.

I also tried using two deployment jobs, one for each environment and then chose job based on conditions, however, as soon as the pipeline involves the prod environment, whether it's going to be used or not, it will ask for approval.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I will start with first last one:

> I also tried using two deployment jobs, one for each environment and then chose job based on conditions, however, as soon as the pipeline involves the prod environment, whether it's going to be used or not, it will ask for approval.

Resource restriction are evaluated on stage level so if you put those deployment jobs on the same stage (or you didn't define a stage - then you have implicit stage) - this is the reason why it asks for approval. If you move deployment jobs to seprate stages you won't be asked for approval. Please keep in mind to move condition to a stage level.

Another apporach it would be conditional for envrionment as follows:

```yaml
jobs:  
- deployment: DeployWeb
  displayName: deploy Web App
  ${{ if eq(variables['Build.SourceBranchName'], 'master') }}:
    environment: 'Dev'
  ${{ if ne(variables['Build.SourceBranchName'], 'master') }}:
    environment: 'campo-dev'
  strategy:
    # Default deployment strategy, more coming...
    runOnce:
      deploy:
        steps:
        - checkout: self 
        - script: echo my first deployment
```

Answer (score 0):

I do this with an extends yaml.  You can define your stages via the environment's parameter (defaulted) and then your calling yaml extends it and passes tasks for build and deploy. The build section is ran once. And the deploy section will loop for each environment.

The approvals comes from the Environment approvals setup in Devops

```
#Extends Yaml

parameters: 
- name: buildSteps
  type: stepList
  default: []
- name: deploySteps
  type: stepList
  default: []
- name: environments
  type: object
  default:
  - name: Stage
    branch: any
    dependsOn:
    - Builds
  - name: Prod
    branch: any
    dependsOn:
    - Stage


stages:
- stage: Builds
  jobs:
  - job: Building
    steps:
    - ${{ each step in parameters.buildSteps }}:
      - ${{ each pair in step }}:
          ${{ pair.key }}: ${{ pair.value }}
        
- ${{ each env in parameters.environments }}:
  - stage: ${{ env.name }}
    dependsOn: ${{ env.dependsOn }}
    condition: and(succeeded(), or(startsWith(variables['Build.SourceBranch'], 'refs/heads/${{ env.branch }}'), eq('${{ env.branch }}', 'any')))
    jobs: 
    - deployment: Deploy${{ env.name }}
      displayName: Deploy to ${{ env.name }}
      variables:
      - group: ENV-${{ env.name }}
      environment: ${{ env.name }}
      strategy:
        runOnce:
          deploy:
            steps:
            - ${{ each step in parameters.deploySteps }}:
              - ${{ each pair in step }}:
                  ${{ pair.key }}: ${{ pair.value }}
```

```
#Calling Yaml

#*Trimmed* header stuff

resources:
  repositories:
    - repository: cicd
      type: git
      name: SharedRepo
      ref: main


extends:
  template: extends-deploy.yaml@cicd
  parameters:
    buildSteps:
      - task: PowerShell@2
        inputs:
        targetType: 'inline'
        script: Write-Host 'Build Stuff 1'

      - task: PowerShell@2
        inputs:
        targetType: 'inline'
        script: Write-Host 'Build Stuff 2'


    deploySteps:
      - task: PowerShell@2
        inputs:
        targetType: 'inline'
        script: Write-Host 'Deploy Stuff 1'

      - task: PowerShell@2
        inputs:
        targetType: 'inline'
        script: Write-Host 'Deploy Stuff 2'
```