# How to specify dynamic value as environment name for virtual machine resource in yaml pipelines

Tags: azure-devops, yaml, azure-yaml-pipelines

We are planning to move our release pipelines to yaml and we are ready with it.

I have multiple environments like dev, test and prod where I'm trying to use same deployment job templates for all environments.

```
jobs:
- deployment: deploy
  displayName: Deploy
  environment: 
    name: dev     # This should be replaced with environment specific variable
    resourceType: VirtualMachine
    tags: WEB01
```

In above code, my intension is to provide name as environment specific variable. Could someone pls help?

Thank you!

Comment: [Define variables](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/devops/pipelines/process/variables?view=azure-devops&tabs=yaml%2Cbatch)

Comment: its not allowing me to add as parameter or variable.

Answer (score 2):

You can do this with parameters, but you need to use the expression syntax which is evaluated when the pipeline is compiled

```
parameters:
  - name: environment
    type: string
    default: dev
    values:
      - dev
      - test
      - preprod
      - prod

jobs:
  - deployment: deploy
    displayName: Deploy
    environment: 
      name: ${{ parameters.environment }}
      resourceType: VirtualMachine
      tags: WEB01
```

Comment: We have added multiple deployment jobs in templates and when im using parameters, it is throwing error like  "A value for environment  parameter must be provided."

Comment: @Kart Could you provide an example of your pipeline and template?

Answer (score 0):

You might like my answer in another post.  it does stages per environment with approvals.

https://stackoverflow.com/a/74159554/4485260